# Why isn't the easing working in this WPF app done entirely in Blend

Tags: wpf, easing

I'm having trouble understanding why easing isn't working in my app. As a test I created a very simple app in Blend and it doesn't work there either. My test app is below. The animation of the Border works fine but there is no easing. What am I missing?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="343.43"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57.926" Margin="36.854,0,0,27.098" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="67.683" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first animation has an Easing KeyTime set to zero seconds, which will appear to have no animation and may explain why it appears to not be working. The second animation appears to be working, by dragging the border from the left side of the screen to the right in one second.

The piece of code i am referencing:

```
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
```

Comment: Changing those values doesn't appear to effect the easing animation.

Comment: If you set your example to the code below, you should notice the two animation...the first one will appear to bounce back and forth for a second, and then after that is done it will ease to the right. If you describe more specific of what you want i can put together an example. 

First Easing
   <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:01" Value="100">

Second Easing
   <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="343.43"/>

Comment: Ohhhh I see. I was only easing the part where the cube starts. Once I added some easing to the part where the cube arrives, it works as planed.   Thanks!